# What are the forces acting on the block?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

> Imagine holding a piece of block with two fingers.
> [image: block_]
>
> The forces acting on it are $mg$ downwards, contact force $F$, and frictional force $f$.[image: fbd]
>
> The block is at equilibrium under the action of this forces. Now move your arm from left to right and then from right to left. Describe the cause of the motion of the block from left to right and right to left.

---

I approached this problem by using $$\sum F_{\text{net},x} = ma$$ I got a relation between Force exerted by left and right finger respectively. Assuming that since I am a human, somehow one of my finger may apply a greater force , but if I replace my fingers to a clip or something nonliving I shall have the same observation. Also, if I willingly apply more force by one of my fingers without moving my arm, the block does not move. I am not able to convince myself of the fact that fingers can apply different force. Has the moving of the arm something to do with this?

---

**Update**
[image: fbd_system]
I could make up the following conclusions after drawing the free-body diagram of the system of bodies.
$$F - \mu_km_1g - \mu_km_2g = Ma$$
$$\mu_km_1g - F_1 = m_1a$$
$$\mu_km_2g + F_2 = m_2a$$

Comment: You have asked this Question before tooo

Comment: I have edited it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question! The block *has* to move to the left and right because of a difference in forces applied by your fingers. The fingers are the only place of contact. If you press the box equal forces on both sides (caused by your fingers) will compress it. When you make the box move this compressing force will still be there (so it won't fall). The difference of force on the box is delivered by your arm. When the box is stationary, the force imposed by your arm is zero. When you make the box move, the force inside your arm is transmitted to one of your fingers, thereby giving it an acceleration (in whatever direction). You can give it an acceleration too by playing around with your fingers. Your arm will be stationary, but the box accelerates (in a small space though, because of the smallness of your fingers). You can even give it angular acceleration.
So your fingers *can* apply different forces. They *have* to, in order to account for your observation. But it's a different force as the pressing finger force.